# Weird output when passing array of pointers - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a two dimensional array of pointers declared in main as

```
char* data[3][8]
```

which I passed into a function

```
void func(char*** data)
```

When I did `printf("%p\n", data[0]);` in `main` and in the function I got different outputs `0x7ffeabc27640` in main and `(nil)` in the function. Albeit printing just `data` outputs the same address with that from inside the `main`. Why can't I access the array in the function.

Comment: Enable warnings and try again.

Comment: The 2D array of pointers you are trying to pass is not a `char ***`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable some warnings (which you should always do), you'll get :

```
main.cpp: In function 'main':
main.cpp:6:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'func' from incompatible pointer type
     func(data);
          ^
main.cpp:2:6: note: expected 'char ***' but argument is of type 'char * (*)[8]'
 void func(char*** data) { (void)data; }
      ^
```

Which tells you exactly what's wrong, namely that an array is not a pointer. Dereferencing a pointer that has been converted to the wrong type is undefined behaviour, so you can get anything back.

Have your function take in a `char *(*)[8]` if you want to give it a `char *(*)[8]` :

```
void func(char *(*data)[8]);
```

Or, if you want to emphasize that `data` should point to the first element of an array :

```
void func(char *data[][8]);
```

The two syntaxes are perfectly equivalent.

Note : the file is named `main.cpp` but is indeed compiled in C mode.

Comment: So just to complete the answer. Your function prototype should either be `foo(char* bar[3][8]);` or `foo(char* bar[][8]);`. If you choose to use the second one, you could also pass the number of elements (of your array's first dimension) as second parameter of the function as @Neil suggested.

Comment: @kimimsc `foo(char* bar[][8])` is sugar for `foo(char *(*bar)[8])`, though. I'm keeping this answer as a minimal solution to the actual error, Neil has dug up a great demonstration and there's no point repeating it.

Comment: Yea I know that but am not sure the OP does since (s)he doesn't seem to know the difference between (char *** and char* [n][m]).

Answer (score 0):

Passing 2D arrays to a function -

This will help you read-up and better understand how to do this...

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/

The below is a snippet from the web-page - showing one example of how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int n = 3;

void print(int arr[][n], int m)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    print(arr, 3);
    return 0;
}

Output:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```